# Rebind grid view in previous popup window from the current popup window using session ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I am working on a project in which I get a dataset and assign this to a session in the newly opened popup window. Now I need to rebind the grid view of the previous popup window using this updated session from the newly opened popup window. How can I implement this.

Details in Elaborate:

1. First Popup window (previous): model.htm inner binds attendee.aspx (in which grdAttendees exists)
2. New pop up: (display.aspx) genertated in button click from attendee.aspx

Referring to some samples i tried this but didn't work.

```
        GridView grv = new GridView();
        grv = ((GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("grdAttendees"));
        grv.DataSource = "";
        if (Session["map_hcp"] != null)
        {
            DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["map_hcp"];
            grv.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

Any better idea to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new gridview inside of your pop-up, and bind it using your session? instead of declaring a new gridview in behind?

Comment: Actually the old popup already exists. The requirement is that we need to open a new pop up and see the the dataset values in the new pop up. If the user clicks ok buton we need to bind the grid in the previous pop up. If he clicks no, then no action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javscript for this
PARENT WINDOW:

```
 function jsparentfunction()
    {
    alert('youve successfully calledme');
    }
```

CHILD WINDOW

```
function executethischildjsfunction()
{
window.opener.jsparentfunction();
window.close();
}
```